# update schedule of a glue crawler on aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I have created an aws crawler to update/sync data between s3 and athena tables using `create_crawler`. I have used the `Schedule` parameter to run it on a schedule, now I wish to update the `schedule` of the crawler to a new time.
I am trying to do using `start_crawler_schedule`, but this takes only the `CrawlerName` as input and no time/cron expression.

At first, I was a bit skeptic to use this function given it's name, my understanding was this function is used to trigger a schedule crawler to run now. But based on [documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/glue.html#Glue.Client.start_crawler_schedule), it looks like this is the function to use to update the schedule except it doesn't take time expression.

> Changes the schedule state of the specified crawler to SCHEDULED , unless the crawler is already running or the schedule state is already SCHEDULED .

In a nutshell, what's the way to update a glue crawler with a new time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/glue.html#Glue.Client.update_crawler_schedule) will help you

> update_crawler_schedule

```py
response = client.update_crawler_schedule(
    CrawlerName='string',
    Schedule='string'
)
```

Comment: "it was right there in the docs", so embarrased to admit how much time I wasted on looking for this, thanks a lot